# in Powershell how to use two system variables to name a file?

Tags: file, powershell, csv, timestamp, export

I'm new to `Powershell`. I'm trying to export file to `.csv` file named with the computer name followed by time stamp. It works for me either with computername or timestamp, but not when both together. So far i have this:

`enter code here`$results | export-csv c:\$(get-content env:computername)$(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm).csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by erroneus `Get-Content`- It would read contents from a file and is not used to read an environment variable. What you are looking for is more like

```
"c:\"+$env:computername+$(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm)+".csv"
# Output:
c:\MyComputer03-07-2013-12-29.csv
```

Comment: Rather than concatenate the different string elements interspersed with variables, you might like to embed the whole expression in a single string like this: "C:\$($env:computername)_$(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm).csv"  [I added an underscore here, which means you need to have the "$($variableName)" syntax to distinguish the variable name from the following string elements]. Note: variable expansion like this is only done when the string is quoted with double-quotes (") rather than single quotes (')

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the `-f` operator.  It makes the code a little easier to read.  When using dates as timestamps, I luse a format that is `YearMonthDayHourMinute`, that way the file is sorted whenever you get a directory listing.

```
$results |
    Export-Csv -Path ('C:\{0}-{1:yyyyMMddHHmm}.csv' -f $env:COMPUTERNAME,(Get-Date))
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I might use the **-f** option as you suggested.